# With VSC, Editor layout split: Word-wrap in side one only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While using Visual Studio Code to work on a file I like to split it into two views. []

On one side I would like to see word-wrap, and on the other just the beginning of each line.

If possible, how can this be done?

Assume HTML, word-wrap on, the left side  lines 70 and 71 are:

70

This is a long line of text which does no change needed.

71

This line need to be fis=xed as it is not right.

and at the same time, on the right,
with word-wrap off:
70

This is a long line of text
71

This line need to be fis=xed

Can this be done? How? Thank you!

Note: Editing did not help me. I wanted the first 70 and 71 to appear as word-warped lines and the second pair as without word-wrapping.

Comment: Note: I tried googling to see if there was an existing issue ticket (bug/feature-request) with "`github vscode issues different word wrap for "split" editor`" and didn't see any great matches in the top search results.

Comment: I just created https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178238